# Configure Column Options for Serilog Sinks MsSqlServer in AppSettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings, serilog

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to configure the column options for serilog sink mssqlserver in the `appsettings.json` file for an ASP.Net Core 2 project.

I create and configure the logger in the `Program.cs` file.

```
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {



            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                //.Enrich.WithProperty("AppName", "One Badass App") // Adds property to XML structure in properties column
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

                try
                {
                    Log.Information("Starting web host");
                    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
                    return 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                    return 1;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Log.CloseAndFlush();
                }
        }
```

I can build the configuration file from the appsettings.json file, which contains a Serilog node with information for which connection string and table to use.

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Application": {
      "Name": "Payment Processing API",
      "Version":  "1.0"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "localPaymentProcessingDb": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PaymentProcessing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PaymentProcessing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
          "tableName": "Logs"
        }
      }
    ]
 }
```

There's an open issue on [Github](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/109) for this, but I haven't found any other information about it.

If column options can't be configured in the `appsettings.json`, where and how should they be configured in an ASP.Net Core 2 project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles across this same issue the linked GitHub issue in the question now contains the answer:

> This is now possible with the latest SQL sink and
>   Serilog.Settings.Configuration packages.

Also, I know this question asks for a .NET Core 2 answer, and it sounds like the linked GitHub page answers this for 2, I am using .NET Core 3.1 and the following worked for me (hopefully it works for 2 as well)

I installed the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` Nuget package and used the following Serilog appsettings.json configuration:

```
"Serilog":{
   "MinimumLevel":"Information",
   "WriteTo":[
      {
         "Name":"MSSqlServer",
         "Args":{
            "connectionString":"DbContext",
            "tableName":"EventLog",
            "autoCreateSqlTable":true,
            "columnOptionsSection":{
               "addStandardColumns":[
                  "LogEvent"
               ],
               "removeStandardColumns":[
                  "MessageTemplate",
                  "Properties"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For accessing Serilog from appsettings in Code, you could bind Serilog node to Serilog class.
Here are the detail steps.
1. Create Serilog Configuration Class

```
    public class SerilogConfiguration
{
    public LogEventLevel MinimumLevel { get; set; }
    public List<WriteTo> WriteTo { get; set; }
}
public class WriteTo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Args Args { get; set; }
}
public class Args
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public List<StandardColumn> Add { get; set; }
    public List<StandardColumn> Remove { get; set; }
}
```

2. Configure appsettings.json

Code:

```
{
    "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Error",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "<our connection string>",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "Remove": [ "Properties" ],
          "Add": [ "LogEvent" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

3. Bind appsetting.json to class

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {           
       services.Configure<SerilogConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("Serilog"));            
   }
   ```
4. Access Configuration

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller    {
   private readonly SerilogConfiguration _configuration;
   public HomeController(IOptions<SerilogConfiguration> configuration)
   {
       _configuration = configuration.Value;
   }       

   public IActionResult AppSettings()
   {
       var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
       var MSSqlServer = _configuration.WriteTo.Where(wt => wt.Name == "MSSqlServer").FirstOrDefault();
       // Don't include the Properties XML column.
       foreach(var columnRemove in MSSqlServer.Args.Remove)
       {
           columnOptions.Store.Remove(columnRemove);
       }
       // Do include the log event data as JSON.
       foreach (var columnAdd in MSSqlServer.Args.Add)
       {
           columnOptions.Store.Add(columnAdd);
       }

       Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(MSSqlServer.Args.ConnectionString, MSSqlServer.Args.TableName, columnOptions: columnOptions,
               restrictedToMinimumLevel: _configuration.MinimumLevel)
           .CreateLogger();
       return Ok("OK");
   }    }
   ```