# How to get current Serilog MinimumLevel

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

Is there a way to get the minimum log level from Serilog's current configuration in a controller or middleware?

Comment: Do you want to get minimum log level from `appsettings.json` or `Serilog.Log.Logger` object? For previous, you could bind the configuration to `IOptions<SerilogConfiguration>`, refer [Configure Column Options for Serilog Sinks MsSqlServer in AppSettings.json
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690921/configure-column-options-for-serilog-sinks-mssqlserver-in-appsettings-json/48701159#48701159)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Though it is slightly indirect, you can use `IsEnabled` to check this level by level:

```
Log.IsEnabled(LogEventLevel.Debug)
```

This is usually enough for these kinds of scenarios. If you really need the precise minimum level, you can try the various `LogEventLevel` members individually to figure it out. `IsEnabled()` is very fast, so checking a few levels this way won't show up on your performance radar.

Keep in mind that the minimum level can still be overridden per source context (i.e. with `MinimumLevel.Override()`).

Comment: Maybe `Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogEventLevel)).Cast<LogEventLevel>().Where(Log.IsEnabled).Min()`? Although I guess a custom loop could short circuit.